# Match words to select and highlight in html strings, including linebreak

Tags: javascript, indexing, syntax-highlighting

I have this code (below) that finds first index and last index in a string then selects and highlights words in html.

It's not working when linebreaks are includes in the html. Also, if the first index of string is not 0, it will add highlight an extra character in last index.

```js
function myFunction() {
   var html = stripHTML(document.getElementById("test"));
 //var html = document.getElementById("test").textContent;


  var search_value = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  var regex = new RegExp(search_value,'g');


 var text = html;
  alert(text);
  while ((match = regex.exec(text)) != null) {
   
 var mix = match.index+match[0].length
 alert("match found at: " + match.index+ " last: " +mix);
  
 setSelectionRange(document.getElementById("test"), match.index, match.index+match[0].length);
    highlight("yellow");
       
    }
    
 
}

function stripHTML(text){
return text.innerText.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, " ").replace(/\s\s+/gm, ' ');
}


function getTextNodesIn(node) {
    var textNodes = [];
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    } else {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; ++i) {
            textNodes.push.apply(textNodes, getTextNodesIn(children[i]));
        }
    }
    return textNodes;
}

function setSelectionRange(el, start, end) {
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var textNodes = getTextNodesIn(el);
        var foundStart = false;
        var charCount = 0, endCharCount;

        for (var i = 0, textNode; textNode = textNodes[i++]; ) {
            endCharCount = charCount + textNode.length;
            if (!foundStart && start >= charCount && (start < endCharCount || (start == endCharCount && i <= textNodes.length))) {
                range.setStart(textNode, start - charCount);
                foundStart = true;
            }
            if (foundStart && end <= endCharCount) {
                range.setEnd(textNode, end - charCount);
                break;
            }
            charCount = endCharCount;
        }

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.selection && document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd("character", end);
        textRange.moveStart("character", start);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
}

function highlight(colour) {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        try {
            if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE <= 8 case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}

function selectAndHighlightRange(id, start, end) {
    setSelectionRange(document.getElementById("test"), start, end);
    highlight("yellow");
}
```

```html
<input id ="textbox" type="text" name="sw" size="20">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<div id="test">here boring text i will break right<br><br><div>now </div><br>here another boring text</div>
```

Comment: jsem, seems like [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)'s  `acrossElements` option is what you're looking for – it will allow you to search across text nodes

Comment: yes i know markjs but its not supported with old browser i need cross browser solution